# Forkjoin followed by foreach causes 'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join

When trying to subscribe to the result of a forkJoin inside the onInit function, I get the following error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type '((next: (value: Result[]) => void, promiseCtor?:
>   PromiseConstructorLike) => Promise) | ((next: (value: Account[])
>   => void, promiseCtor?: PromiseConstructorLike) => Promise)' has no compatible call signatures.

getAccounts returns an observable of Account[], getResults returns an observable of Result[].
When both are finished loading, I'm trying to get the detailed account results from another database, using the accessToken of the accounts retrieved from the getAccounts function, so that I can add the results to the detailed accounts.

In short I'm trying to achieve this:

```
let var = getAccountsSimplified();
let var2 = getAllResults();

if both are finished{
    foreach(acc in var) {
        account = getDetailedAccount(acc.id)
        var ownedResults = var2.where(userid === acc.id)
        account.results = ownedResults
    }
}
```

This is what I tried so far, but for some reason it is causing the error mentioned above.
For some reason the `console.log(user)` is working fine, which is why I'm completely lost at the error.

```js
const tasks$ = [
      this.aus.getAccounts(this.auth.token),
      this.rs.getResults(this.auth.token)
    ];

    forkJoin(tasks$).subscribe(
      value => {
        const userList = value[0];
        const resultList = value[1];
        userList.forEach((acc: Account) => {
          this.aus.getUserDetails(acc.access_token).subscribe((user: User) => {
            if (user != null) {
              console.log(user);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    );
```

Signatures of called functions:

```js
  getAccounts(auth: string): Observable<Array<Account>> {
  }

  getResults(auth: string): Observable<Array<Result>> {
  }

  getUserDetails(token: string): Observable<User> {
  }
```

**Update**
After adding Kurt's suggestion, I'm now getting

> Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<[Account[], Result[]]>' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type
>   'OperatorFunction<(Observable | Observable)[],
>   [Account[], Result[]]>'.   Types of parameters 'source' and 'source'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type 'Observable<(Observable | Observable)[]>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable<[Account[], Result[]]>'.
>         Type '(Observable | Observable)[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Account[], Result[]]': 0,
>   1ts(2345)

It seems as if there is a problem with the returned type of the forkjoin.

**Update 2**
Turns out removing the tasks$ array and adding the functions directly to the forkjoin solved the problem.

Comment: 1) Could you post the signatures of the functions you are calling. 2) What purpose does resultList serve? 3) You're probably want to use a switchMap instead of an inner subscribe.

Comment: @KurtHamilton resultList will be iterated over to get the results matching the userid. Currently I'm not yet using it since I'd like to fix the error first.
As for switchMap, wouldn't that cause problems by breaking off the observable when a new value is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your nested subscription into a `switchMap`.

I have refactored your example to:

1. Save the `resultList` out to some variable or property - that can be used later
2. Pass the `userList` onto a `switchMap`
3. Use `switchMap` to `forkJoin` all of the calls to `getUserDetails`
4. The array of user details now arrives in your subscribe, and you have access to the result list

```js
const tasks$ = [
  this.getAccounts(),
  this.getResults()
];

forkJoin(tasks$).pipe(
  tap((value: [ Account[], Result[] ]) => this.resultList = value[1]),
  map((value: [ Account[], Result[] ]) => value[0]),
  switchMap(accounts => forkJoin(
    accounts.map(x => this.getUserDetails(x.access_token))
  ))
).subscribe(details => {
  this.userList = details.filter(x => !!x);
  console.log(this.resultList);
});
```

This example is from my demo below, which demonstrates the concept rather than using your exact calls and setup.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewbm

Comment: I'm now getting another error on the line containing the tap, it seems as if for some reason there is a problem with the result of forkjoin being an observable instead of an array. I'll add it to my original post

Comment: I tried to mimic your example as closely as possible in my stackblitz. I did have to explicitly type the result of the forkJoin due to the mixed types in the array.

Comment: Found the problem, turned out it had something to do with my tasks$ array, thanks for your help!